# PHP nested for loop to position icon sprite

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, sprite

I am trying to automate 100 icons in a set. I have a image sprite that is 320px x 320px containing 100 icons, each 32px x 32px. What I'd like to achieve is to have a php loop where I can reproduce the icon div code 100 times, but within that loop, use other loops to position the background of the image sprite. What I need to do, is increment the x coordinate 32 px, from 0 to -288 for the first 10, and the y coordinate will be 0. Then repeat the x code again from 0 to -288, but increment the y coordinate 32px, and so on. So for each line of 10 icons the x  gets increased by 32px every time then resets to 0 and the y coordinate gets increased once every 10 icons until a total of 100 icons are reached. I have the following code that successfully loops the 100 icon total, but can't get the nested loop working. Hope this makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
   for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) { ?>
   <div id="menu_icon_edit_cont">
      <div class="menu_icons" style="background-position: -<?= (x coordinate here) ?>px -<?= (y coordinate here) ?>px">
      </div>
   </div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do this, what you choose should be what you find the easiest to read and maintain.

A mistake newbies often make is assuming their for loop needs to exactly mimic what what they want to do (You want 100 icons so you assume you should just iterate from 1 to 100).

What you really want is the end product, such as:

```
    for ($y = 0; $y < 320; $y += 32) {
        for ($x = 0; $x > -320; $x -= 32) {
            //output your html using $x/$y
        }
    }
```

Going the route you posted though it would probably look like:

```
    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){

        $x = $i%10 * -32;
        $y = floor($i/10)*32;

        //output your html using $x/$y
    }
```

I prefer the first way as it is much clearer on exactly what it is intended to do.

Comment: Thanks for these answers, savageguy. I'm going to try and implement these and see how I go.

Answer (score 1):

You can "convert" your single iterator `$i` into coordinates easily enough: `$y = floor($i/10); $x = $i%10;`. Then it's just a case of multiplying by the image's width (in this case 32) and you're done.

Comment: Kolink, thanks for this answer. I am having trouble translating this to my code. Would you be able to demonstrate how this would relate to my code? Much appreciated :)